# Kubernetes defaults to http health checks when using AWS Network Load balancer when externalTrafficPolicy is set to Local

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-elb

I'm trying to set up an AWS NLB for service running on Kubernetes cluster with TCP health checks for the backend service. Kubernetes always tends to create HTTP health checks for any service when the **externalTrafficPolicy** is set to **Local** and only creates TCP health checks if set to **Cluster**

```
.metadata.annotations.service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-type: "nlb"
.metadata.annotations.service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-internal: "true"
.metadata.annotations.service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-backend-protocol: tcp
.spec.ports.protocol: TCP
.spec.externalTrafficPolicy : **Cluster/Local**
```

Only when I switch externalTrafficPolicy to Cluster from Local, i can get my TCP health checks set for my target groups, else it tends to setup a HTTP check on /healthz , which would fail for me.

I'm trying to avoid additional load balancing via kubeproxy with cluster externalTrafficPolicy, which could create hop across node boundaries.

Is there something that I'm missing?

Comment: You said "else it tends to setup a HTTP check on /healthz , which would fail for me", what you mean by "which would fail for me"?

Comment: @mWatney My service is not serving Http and is TCP , so any NLB health checks using HTTP would fail. Below is my deployment.                                                                      `spec:
  ports:                                                                       
     -port: 8888
      name: port-1
      targetPort: 8888                                                                                          
      protocol: TCP`

Comment: Please notice that (when using externaltrafficpolicy local) nodePort and healthCheckNodePort are different (`kubectl get svc <lbname> -oyaml`) nodePort is used for communication with your application and healthCheckNodePort is used as a healthcheck endpoint by NLB. Please check if you can access healthCheckNodePort manually (`curl <nodeip>:<healthCheckNodePort>/healthz`).